# How does temperature affect voltage references, resistors etc.?

Tags: temperature

I have a 0.1% 3V reference with a temperature coefficient of 100ppm/°C.

Does this mean it will be off by 8500ppm (0.085%) on top of my 0.1% when operating in an environment at 85°C?

Does something similar apply to resistors?

Comment: Resistance varies with temperature, and the noise generated by resistors increases with temperature, too.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance#Temperature_dependence

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tempco can be specced from any part of chart. Its better to look at datasheet and see what do they mean by this coefficient. 85C looks too high for normal operating point. On the other hand if there is no access to datasheet, then its safest to treat the 100ppm number as worst case at the end of temperature range.

Say normal t=20C, then at 85C the error will be Unom*65*100/1000000 = +/-0.0195v and +/-0.1% initial error

Answer (score 2):

The 0.1% means that the voltage can be 0.1% off at the rated temperature, which is usually 20°C. Since the temperature coefficient (TC) is positive and you're talking about higher temperatures you should count on +0.1%, not -0.1%, for worst case calculations. (For worst case calculations always make sure that errors add instead of cancel each other out.) 
So at 20°C your reference will be 3.003V worst case.
At 85°C the voltage may increase by 100 ppm/°C \$\times\$ (85°C - 20°C) = 6500 ppm, or 0.65%. So the voltage will be 3.003V \$\times\$ 100.65% = 3.023V.

Yes, it also applies to resistors. Temperature coefficients range from a low 5 ppm to 250 ppm, depending on the materials used. **Thick film** resistors are the least temperature stable with a TC of 200 to [500 ppm](http://www.vishay.com/docs/68036/rchr.pdf). The widest variation can be found in **metal film** and **thin film** resistors, with some precision types having a TC as low as [5 ppm](http://www.vishay.com/docs/60082/pltt.pdf), while others have a TC of [200 ppm](http://www.vishay.com/docs/31013/ccf07.pdf).
If you would use a resistor divider to scale down your reference voltage, choose the same type for both resistors, then you don't have to account for TCs.